# Why Python sorts items differently that VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Create a simple extensionless file in VS Code. And put this content in it:

```
[
    'go',
    'go dark',
]
```

Then select the two lines that contain items, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to sort them.

It becomes:

```
[
    'go dark',
    'go'
]
```

However, running this Python code results in a different order:

```
items = ['go', 'go dark']
sortedItems = sorted(items)
print(sortedItems)
# prints ['go', 'go dark']
```

Why is it so? Why VS Code has a different sorting behavior than Python?

Comment: Python sorts the content of the string, VS Code the whole line. And `"'"` is sorted after `" "` (space). Test it with `sorted(["'", " "])`

Answer (score 3):

Because VS Code does not interpret the content, so it's actually sorting *the lines themselves*, not their meaning as Python code.

A better comparison would be something like this:

```py
items = ["    'go',", "    'go dark',"]
sortedItems = sorted(items)
print(sortedItems)

for item in sortedItems:
    print(item)
```

This should give the same output as VS Code:

```
["    'go dark',", "    'go',"]
    'go dark',
    'go',
```